# Trying to provide a value into variable that is a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to provide a string value into this function and can't solve my problem.
I have an array and a function that checks if value is included in the array.

It looks like this:

```
const movies = [ 'The fantastic Fox', 'Mr. Bean', 'Mr. and Mrs. Ms', 'Mrs. Qnn' ];
const findSentence = movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes('Mrs')})
```

For now it prints "Mrs" but
what i want it is to put whatever i want into findSentence variable.
So if i write findSentence('Mrs') it checks for 'Mrs'.
I thought it might look like this but it doesn't work

```
const findSentence(string) = movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes(string)})
```

Anyone got an idea how could i change it to achive what i want?

Comment: make it a function `const findSentence = (string) => movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes(string)})` and call it `findSentence("Mrs")` or jut make a variable `string = "Mrs"` and use it in the call `const findSentence = movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes(string)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `() =>` syntax

```js
const movies = [ 'The fantastic Fox', 'Mr. Bean', 'Mr. and Mrs. Ms', 'Mrs. Qnn' ];
const findSentence = (str) => movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes(str)});
console.log(findSentence('Mrs'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be defined findSentence function.

```js
const movies = [ 'The fantastic Fox', 'Mr. Bean', 'Mr. and Mrs. Ms', 'Mrs. Qnn' ];
const findSentence = (string) => movies.find(sentence => {return sentence.includes(string)});
console.log(findSentence('Mrs'));
```